# Looking for File in Folder with Command Line

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to find a file stored in a folder on my desktop using command line. Can someone tell me why I can't locate the file itself? It is definitely there....

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems HelloWorld.java is not a Directory. So why are you trying to cd into it? Show us the output of ls in that Programming directory.

Comment: Could you please post text files and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: For your future questions: OS X is not Ubuntu and off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. You can ask questions about it on [Apple.SE]. In this case we’ll allow it because your issue is common to all Unix-like operating systems including Ubuntu. :-)

Comment: Will do! Sorry for bothering you guys with this question in the first place; I didn't realize this was such a professionally-minded platform. Thanks for the link to Ask Different!

Answer (score 3):

You `cd` to your `~/Desktop/Programming` directory, then you do

```
cd Desktop/Programming/HelloWorld.java
```

There are two issues

This is a relative path. You can only `cd` to a path starting `Desktop` if `Desktop` is a subdirectory of the *current working directory* - in this case, you're in a subdirectory of `Desktop`... The full path would be `~/Desktop/Programming/HelloWorld.java` - this will refer to the file you want no matter what the current working directory is.

But if you try to `cd` to that, you will get the error `is not a directory` because `cd` means change directory to the following. So, what are you actually trying to do with that file? You can't `cd` to it.

If you do `ls` after `cd Desktop/Programming`, you will see your file, and you are ideally located to do whatever you like, for example

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

to compile the code...

Comment: Thank you very much! I was a bit frazzled because I didn't know what to do at all to be able to find the HelloWorld.java file. What you said is really helpful, though!

Comment: @MeredithMichael awesome, glad you were able to figure it out :) have fun programming!

Comment: @meredithmichael to put it simple, you cant cd into file, you only cd into folders

Answer (score 2):

Your cd command tries to change to a .java file, you must change to the folder it is in

```
cd ~/Desktop/Programming
```

Then use the command `ls` to list the files in the directory, or in one line.

```
ls ~/Desktop/Programming
```

Will show the contents without changing to the folder.

Comment: @DavidFoerster It says .java, edited but hardly worth a downvote.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That explains it, I was confused thinking the downvote was for a typo :)